# Object Detection using FERNS

Tags: opencv

I am new to image processing and have just started working in **OpenCV**. I was trying to do object detection using **GenericDescriptorMatcher** of type **fern**. But I don't know what to pass as the `params_filename`. What should be the format of the file? What parameters do I write in the file and in what format?

```
Ptr<GenericDescriptorMatcher> descriptorMatcher = GenericDescriptorMatcher::create("FERN", params_filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

The opencv-2.x.x/samples/cpp should contain an example version of 'fern_params.xml', which according to opencv-2.4.8 contains the following xml content,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
    <nclasses>0</nclasses>
    <patchSize>31</patchSize>
    <signatureSize>INT_MAX</signatureSize>
    <nstructs>50</nstructs>
    <structSize>9</structSize>
    <nviews>1000</nviews>
    <compressionMethod>0</compressionMethod>
</opencv_storage>
```